# Can't use softspace attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to experiment with softspace attribute of a file object.

```
fo = open("foo.txt","wb")
print("Softspace flag:",fo.softspace)
```

When running this code, it printed the error that "'_io.BufferedWriter' object has no attribute 'softspace'". Is it true that Python 3.7 has eliminated softspace attribute out of file operation, just like raw_input replaced by raw?

Answer (score 2):

Softspace was used by the `print` statement.  The `print` function introduced in Python3 doesn't use it, it was [removed in Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.0.html?highlight=softspace#print-is-a-function). From [PEP3105](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/#id9), which introduced the print function:

> The softspace feature (a semi-secret attribute on files currently used
>   to tell print whether to insert a space before the first item) will be
>   removed. Therefore, there will not be a direct translation for
>   today's:
>
> print "a", print
>
> which will not print a space between the "a" and the newline.